# Extract the results of a function

Tags: r, function

I have the following function that is to be minimized:

```
calloptim <- function( under,strike, rf, ttoe,par) {(-(under*par[1]
  -strike*exp(-rf*ttoe)*par[2]))^2}
```

I create the following object:

```
res<- nlminb(c(1,1), calloptim, under= 90, strike = 100, rf =0.05, ttoe=3)

res

$par
[1] 0.9771973 1.0218072

$objective
[1] 3.412923e-16

$convergence
[1] 1

$iterations
[1] 2

$evaluations
function gradient 
      34        4 

$message
[1] "false convergence (8)"
```

This is fine but now I want to grab to $par estimate values and put them in a vector so I can use them for other calculations.

How do you isolate and save only parts of the result of an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following are all roughly equivalent:

```
res$par
res["par"]
res[1]
res[[1]]
```

Look at the help page for `?Extract` for details. I often find looking at the `str()` of the object helpful when trying to find where to grab things from, i.e. either the name to of the object to extract or it's numerical location within the object you're looking at (1 in this case).

Comment: I would guess the OP would prefer the first and fourth of these options ... `res[["par"]]` is another option (equivalent to #1 and #4)

Comment: I would probably include in this answer a note that there _is_ an important difference between `res[1]` and `res[[1]]` that is often a source of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this exactly answers what you are asking, but:

```
vector <- res$par
> vector
[1] 0.9771973 1.0218072
> vector[1]
[1] 0.9771973
```

There may be an accessor method that is more 'proper.'

Comment: There is no better accessor method (although it's very a good question to consider). The class of the result of `nlminb()` is `list`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Naive mistake on my part, to not verify the output type.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the `$par` member out of `res` with `newVals <- res$par`

Answer (score 1):

If this is an extension of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334332/passing-multiple-starting-values-to-nlminb), you can extract those nested answers with:

```
out <- apply(f, 1, nlminb, objective=calloptim, under=90, strike=100, rf=0.05, ttoe=3)
out.par <- lapply(out, '[',1)
unlist(out.par, recursive=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. This would have been the next question so you read my mind. Before posting this question I had input out$par and it came back NULL.

Comment: You're welcome.  On this and your other questions, its customary to up vote answers that were helpful in solving your problem and accept the one that does.  (We'll earn reputation and you'll earn reputation and badges.)

Comment: Ah, understood will do, and will vote up when my rep gets to 15.

Comment: in this case, the bracket is being used as a function.  see `?'['` you can think of `'['` as a shorthand for `subset`.  You will almost always use brackets in pairs except for this special case where the `apply` family is looking for a function, and the one you supply happens to be `'['`.