# Extracting results of a function

Tags: r, function

I've looked here but couldn't solve my problem: [Extract the results of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336071/extract-the-results-of-a-function)

Let's say we have this dummy function that returns what a user wrote, how can I extract what is inside this function. I draw inspiration from such functions as say those used in machine learning algorithms. For instance this kind of function:

```
z<-train(.........)#just an example
```

From the above I can extract several results e.g, `z$finalmodel #an example` and so on. How is this done?
Here is my example function:

```
dummy_fun<-function(x,y){
  y<-deparse(substitute(y))
  x<-deparse(substitute(x))
  z<-data.frame(X=x,Y=y)
  q<-print(paste0("You wrote ",x," and ", y))

}
res<-dummy_fun(Hi,There)
```

The `dummy_fun` contains objects z and q, how can I extract them?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: just add last line in your function `return(list(z = z, q = q))` and then you can do `res$z` and so on

Comment: Nice, do you mind posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simpler function could be (without `deparse(substitute())`:

```
dummy_fun<-function(x,y){
  z<-data.frame(X=x,Y=y)
  q<-paste0("You wrote ",x," and ", y)
  return(list(z = z, q = q))
 }
```

which when called with arguments:

```
> dummy_fun(x = 1, y = 2)
$z
  X Y
1 1 2

$q
[1] "You wrote 1 and 2"
```